# How to extract the value id from the json (Grail)

Tags: html, json, grails

json

```
categories": [
    {
        "id" : "A", "name" : "bed_room","description" : "Bedroom"........
```

controller

```
     def categories = Catalogue.categories
[categories: categories]
```

Gsp

```
<g:each in="${categories}" var="category">
              <li>
                ${category.value.id}
              </li>
            </g:each>
```

on html page

It prints: [A, B, C, D...]

The external json file resides inside directory and the categories are obtained into array. I am trying to display the elements in html

Like this:

```
<li>A</li>
<li>B</li>
```

But it currently prints one array of all items: [A, B, C, D...] which is not correct.

How do I display these elements in html?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your full json. You can try to send data `as JSON` from controller.

Comment: the output you get there is the toString() from the array in groovy.  most likely the data you provide contain some error/double nesting/... at first glance your code looks ok.

Comment: @user1791574 - full json would be longer so it is not good idea to post it. I only show id which I need to extract

Comment: @cfrick hmm i see string category in domain class. in my own controller, it has categories inside list which will be displayed but not as I expected...

Comment: then something beforehand already casted the list down to the string. maybe a simple typo? ``categories.id`` instead of ``category.id`` somewhere? ``categories.id`` is short for ``categories*.id`` which would give you a list of your ids.

Comment: @cfrick im trying and looking around. thanks :D

Comment: I am not sure about this, but you can try   <g:each in="${categories}" var="category">
 <g:each in="${category}" var="cat">
              <li>
                ${cat.id}
              </li>
            </g:each>
</g:each>

Comment: @swapnilsawant - why two g:each? so far i got category.id working.

Comment: @kittymeows because you have a map of categories and each categories is an array of Json objects, that's why I suggested 2 g:each.